# Downloading folders from aws s3, cp or sync?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

If I want to download all the contents of a directory on S3 to my local PC, which command should I use cp or sync ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

For example,

if I want to download all the contents of "this folder" to my desktop, would it look like this ?

```
 aws s3 sync s3://"myBucket"/"this folder" C:\\Users\Desktop
```

Answer (score 433, accepted):

Using `aws s3 cp` from the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) will require the `--recursive` parameter to copy multiple files.

```
aws s3 cp --recursive s3://myBucket/dir localdir
```

The `aws s3 sync` command will, by default, copy a whole directory. It will only copy new/modified files.

```
aws s3 sync s3://mybucket/dir localdir
```

Just experiment to get the result you want.

Documentation:

- [cp command](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/cp.html)
- [sync command](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)

Comment: Took me a few minutes to figure out where to get aws cli. Here it is: https://aws.amazon.com/cli/

Comment: ```aws s3 cp s3://myBucket/dir localdir --recursive```. This works like a charm. If the --recursive flag is skipped, it throws a rather unhelpful error: ```fatal error: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Key "myBucket" does not exist```

Comment: But if the file single zip large size in GBs, what would be the recommandation?

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar Please create a new Question rather than asking via a comment on an old question.

Comment: I just want to add: `localdir` is necessary, annoyingly. AWS CLI will only copy the directory contents, not the directory itself.

Answer (score 15):

Just used version 2 of the AWS CLI. For the s3 option, there is also a --dryrun option now to show you what will happen:

`aws s3 --dryrun cp s3://bucket/filename /path/to/dest/folder --recursive`

Answer (score 6):

In case you need to use another profile, especially cross account. you need to add the profile in the config file

```
[profile profileName]
region = us-east-1
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::XXX:role/XXXX
source_profile = default
```

and then if you are accessing only a single file

```
aws s3 cp s3://crossAccountBucket/dir localdir --profile profileName
```

---

Answer (score 5):

In the case you want to download a single file, you can try the following command:

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket/filename /path/to/dest/folder
```

Answer (score 3):

You've many options to do that, but the best one is using the AWS CLI.

Here's a walk-through:

1. Download and install AWS CLI in your machine:

   - [Install the AWS CLI using the MSI Installer (Windows)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html#install-msi-on-windows).
   - [Install the AWS CLI using the Bundled Installer for Linux, OS X, or Unix](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html#install-bundle-other-os).
2. Configure AWS CLI:

[image]

Make sure you input valid **access** and **secret** keys, which you received when you created the account.

3. Sync the S3 bucket using:

   ```
    aws s3 sync s3://yourbucket/yourfolder /local/path
   ```

In the above command, replace the following fields:

- `yourbucket/yourfolder` >> your S3 bucket and the folder that you want to download.
- `/local/path` >> path in your local system where you want to download all the files.

Answer (score 2):

`sync` method first lists both source and destination paths and copies only differences (name, size etc.).

`cp --recursive` method lists source path and copies (overwrites) all to the destination path.

If you have possible matches in the destination path, I would suggest `sync` as one LIST request on the destination path will save you many unnecessary PUT requests - meaning cheaper and possibly faster.

Answer (score 0):

aws s3 cp  s3:// --recursive(if pushing multiple file)